# extract files to a relative path from a tar file that was creating with -P flag

Tags: bash, tar

I'm creating a tar file using the `-P` flag, meaning that all paths are absolute (leading `/` is not stripped from files names). I use it because I'm tarring multiple directories and I need each file to be extracting to its correct location.

I'm using a script to extract the tar file, and I need an ability to extract the files to another directory if an optional argument is provided.

I create the tar file like this:

```
tar pcjfPv "${ARCHIVE_NAME}".tmp.bz  ${DIR_A} ${DIR_B}
```

`${DIR_A}` is `/path/a` and  `${DIR_B}` is `/path/b`.

If I execute the extracting script with no argument I expect the files to go to their correct directories. This part works as expected with `tar mxfvjpP`.

However when the script recies a path in the argument I want to extract the files to `/path/from/argument/path/a` and `/path/from/argument/path/b`.

Is this even possible? This is what I currently have:

```
if [ ! -d "${EXTRACT_TO}" ]; then
    echo "${EXTRACT_TO} does not exist, creating."
    mkdir -p ${EXTRACT_TO}
fi
tar mxfvjP - -C ${EXTRACT_TO}
```

That does not work. The path in `${EXTRACT_TO}` is created, but the files are still extracted to `/path/a` and `/path/b`.

**NOTE**: I can't modify the tar file.

Comment: Don't create tar with `-P` and extract with `-C /`.

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks, that exactly what I ended up doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my Debian extracting *without* `-P` yields `Removing leading '/' from member names`. Maybe all you need is not to use `-P` while extracting to another directory.

---

If there's any problem with the above approach, consider `--transform`. From `man 1 tar`:

> `--transform=EXPRESSION`, `--xform=EXPRESSION`
>   Use `sed` replace `EXPRESSION` to transform file names.

So this

```
tar -x --transform='s|^/||' …
```

will remove one leading slash (if it's there) from each path. But because [`////foo` is equivalent to `/foo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/1919/108618), the following seems better:

```
tar -x --transform='s|^/*||' …
```

It will remove all leading slashes.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up compressing without `-P` and using `-C /` and `-C ${EXTRACT_TO}`